# Can we detect "trivial relocatability" in C++17?

Tags: c++, object, memory, c++17, type-traits

In future standards of C++, we will have the concept of "trivial relocatability", which means we can simply copy bytes from one object to an uninitialized chunk of memory, and simply ignore/zero out the bytes of the original object. 
this way, we imitate the C-style way of copying/moving objects around.

In future standards, we will probably have something like `std::is_trivially_relocatable<type>` as a type trait. currently, the closest thing we have is `std::is_pod<type>` which will be deprecated in C++20.

My question is, do we have a way in the current standard (C++17) to figure out if the object is trivially relocatable? 
For example, `std::unique_ptr<type>` can be moved around by copying its bytes to a new memory address and zeroing out the original bytes, but `std::is_pod_v<std::unique_ptr<int>>` is `false`.

Also, currently the standard mandate that every uninitialized chunk of memory must pass through a constructor in order to be considered a valid C++ object. even if we can somehow figure out if the object is trivially relocatable, if we just move the bytes - it's still UB according to the standard. 
So another question is - even if we can detect trivial relocatability, how can we implement trivial relocation without causing UB? simply calling `memcpy + memset(src,0,...)` and casting the memory address to the right type is UB.
`

Thanks!

Comment: The whole reason for inventing something new is that we cannot do it without the new thing...

Comment: @MarcGlisse the fact that something is not fully standardized, doesn't mean it doesn't exist, or not possible. people had used multi-threading in C++ way before it was standardized in 2011. STL is another example

Comment: And you are basing your definition of `is_trivially_relocatable` on proposal [P1144R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1144r3.html), right?

Comment: The proposal talks about using an attribute to mark a type as trivially relocatable. There's no way a compiler is going to be smart enough to just look at the code and figure out if it's trivially relocatable. A programmer has to look at the implementation of, say `std::unique_ptr` and *understand* whether it is trivially relocatable. It sounds like that's what you're asking for.

Comment: @Kerndog73 well, let's say your struct only contains `int`s, or only contain pointers to numeral types - the compiler can deduce that the type is in fact trivially relocatable. so for many cases, the compiler can do it. I also don't think there's an absolute way to achieve it

Comment: @DavidHaim There are some simple rules about assuming a struct is trivially relocatable if its members are trivially relocatable but there's no way to detect that without `std::is_trivially_relocatable`.

Comment: @DavidHaim Without any types specifically tagged as trivially relocatable either by attribute or in the standard library, I think the definition of `is_trivially_relocatable` boils down to `is_trivially_copyable`.

Comment: @walnut unfortunately, because unique_ptr and std::vector are trivially relocatable but not trivially copiable. my question is if there's a way to hack it (at least partially) and if so, how to implement it.

Comment: Did you check what code your compiler generates when relocating a vector or a unique_ptr? You don't always need a new language feature to perform some optimization.

Comment: It might be possible to avoid false positives (think a type is TR when it's not) by using `std::is_trivially_copyable` or maybe something else. I don't think it's possible to avoid false negatives without explicitly tagging TR types. False positives will cause crashes (hopefully!) but false negatives will work fine with suboptimal performance.

Comment: If you just want a partial hack, there is for instance `__is_bitwise_relocatable` in libstdc++ (the proposal has links to others).

Comment: @MarcGlisse there's a reason I ask. I've implemented my own `std::function` which uses type erasure on the callable to achieve it (plus SBO optimization). in order to move my `std::function` I call a function pointer/virtual `move_to` function. what I want to do is to shave away the indirection by moving the bytes if the type supports it. if the type is safe for trivial relocation, I can set the function pointer to some stub when assigning the callable. when moving, I want to test against that stub and move the bytes inline, without calling any function pointer .

Comment: Is moving a `std::function` really "hot code"? Kind of sounds like the root of all evil to me.

Comment: if your code uses a lot of callbacks/task queues, it might be. I'm not religious about it though, if it too ugly or complicated, I'll give it up. if there's something relatively small, the optimization is worth it, I think.

Comment: Did you measure?

Comment: Even if it takes 0.5% of execution time, and it's very simply to implement, it's worth it.

Comment: `std::is_trivially_copyable` is probably the best you can do

Comment: If you don't mind tagging lambdas as trivially relocatable then that might be worth the effort. But if you have "a lot of callbacks" then retroactively finding them all and tagging them appropriately could become a nightmare.

Comment: uses a lot of callbacks doesn't mean that there are many callback types. it could only use 10 different callback types, but use them billions of times. for example, a socket handler - only one type, but used for billiards of requests.

Comment: You could use `noexcept` to mark functions as trivially relocatable. `noexcept(true)` for trivially relocatable closures and `noexcept(false)` for the rest. Omitting the `noexcept` specification could leave it either way. You could use a macro to make your intentions clear like `#define TRIVIALLY_RELOCATABLE(X) noexcept(X)`. Then it's a simple matter of checking if the callable is `noexcept`.

Comment: A cleaner (but dirtier, depending on how you look at things) would be to use a wrapper return type like `trivially_relocatable<actual_return_type>` but implementing the wrapper properly is a pretty big effort (just look at how big `std::pair` is)

Comment: @DavidHaim: "*the closest thing we have is std::is_pod<type> which will be deprecated in C++20.*" FYI: Trivially copyable is the closest thing we have, which is not being deprecated in any standard. The POD definition is being removed because its utility has been subsumed by trivially copyable and standard layout.

Comment: "In future standards of C++, we will have the concept [...]" There's a proposal, I'm not sure you can say with this level of confidence that it will definitely happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of trivial-relocatability is to enable byte-wise moving of objects even in the presence of a non-trivial move constructor or move assignment operator.

**Edit:** removed incorrect statement about P1144.

It is, of course, possible that you define your own `is_trivially_relocatable` trait that defaults to `std::is_trivially_copyable_v` and have the user specialize for types that should specifically be considered trivially-relocatable. Even this is problematic, however, because there's gonna be no way to automatically propagate this property to types that are composed of trivially-relocatable types…

Even for trivially-copyable types, you can't just copy the bytes of the object representation to some random memory location and cast the address to a pointer to the type of the original object. Since an object was never created, that pointer will not point to an object. And attempting to access the object that pointer doesn't point to will result in undefined behavior. Trivial-copyabibility means you can copy the bytes of the object representation from one existing object to another existing object and rely on that making the value of the one object equal to the value of the other [[basic.types]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#3).

To do this for trivially-relocating some object would mean that you have to first construct an object of the given type at your target location, then copy the bytes of the original object into that, and then modify the original object in a way equivalent to what would have happened if you had moved from that object. Which is essentially a complicated way of just moving the object…

There's a reason a proposal to add the concept of trivial-relocatability to the language exists: because you currently just can't do it from within the langugage itself…

Note that, despite all this, just because the compiler frontend cannot avoid generating constructor calls doesn't mean the optimizer cannot eliminate unnecessary loads and stores. Let's have a look at what code the compiler generates for your example of moving a `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`:

```cpp
auto test1(void* dest, std::vector<int>& src)
{
    return new (dest) std::vector<int>(std::move(src));
}

auto test2(void* dest, std::unique_ptr<int>& src)
{
    return new (dest) std::unique_ptr<int>(std::move(src));
}
```

[As you can see](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:15),source:%27%23include+%3Cnew%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%0A%0Aauto+test1(void*+dest,+std::vector%3Cint%3E%26+src)%0A%7B%0A++++return+new+(dest)+std::vector%3Cint%3E(std::move(src))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aauto+test2(void*+dest,+std::unique_ptr%3Cint%3E%26+src)%0A%7B%0A++++return+new+(dest)+std::unique_ptr%3Cint%3E(std::move(src))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), just doing an actual move often already boils down to just copying and overwriting some bytes, even for non-trivial types…

Comment: thanks for detailed answer, I will accept it in the near future. read my comments: it's not like I don't trust the optimizer, I have a specific case I want to optimize.

Comment: @DavidHaim If asking for how to solve your specific case is part of your question, I would suggest to add this to your question since its kinda hard to find down in the comments. For the reasons laid out above, I don't think there's much you can do here except for introducing a custom trait. Also, note that `std::function` generally already performs small buffer optimization, so there's probably no need to implement your own in the first place…

Comment: there is, because the crappy std::function gets it callable by value. mine builds the callable in place from its arguments. if your callbacks use a lot of unique pointers (mine do) std::function become a stick in my code's wheels. also, my std::function has some functions like `execute_destroy` which invokes the underlying callable and destroys it in one function call (which is of course, indirect). it's extremely useful for one-time callbacks (like the ones you submit to threadpool, socket callbacks, etc.)

Comment: @DavidHaim I'm having trouble imagining a case where this would matter. That particular `std::function` constructor is almost certainly going to be inlined. Unless you're dealing with callables that have user-defined copy-constructors with side-effects (given the question here, I'd imagine that not to be the case), I'd be very surprised if passing the callable by value vs in-place construction would make a difference…

Comment: if your callable contains unique_ptr and you try to construct a std::function from it, it'll fail to compile, since you cannot copy a unique_ptr

Comment: @DavidHaim I'm not sure why exactly this happens, given that this `std::function` constructor [is supposed to](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/func.wrap.func#con-10) `std::move` its argument into the `std::function` object. But the requirements state that the callable shall be `CopyConstructible`, so I guess this is valid behavior for an implementation. So fair enough, I guess I just didn't run into this yet since I don't use `std::function` (or anything like it) for anything really…

Answer (score 8):

Author of [P1144](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1144r6.html) here; somehow I'm just seeing this SO question now!

`std::is_trivially_relocatable<T>` is *proposed* for some-future-version-of-C++, but I don't predict it'll get in anytime soon (definitely not C++23, I bet not C++26, quite possibly not ever). The paper ([P1144R6](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1144r6.html), June 2022) ought to answer a lot of your questions, especially the ones where people are correctly answering that if you could already implement this in present-day C++, we wouldn't need a proposal. See also [my 2019 C++Now talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGdfPextuAU&ab_channel=CppNow).

Michael Kenzel's answer previously said that P1144 "ultimately requires that a user *manually* mark types for which [trivial relocation] is possible"; I want to point out that that's kind of the opposite of the point. The *state of the art* for trivial relocatability is manual marking ("warranting") of each and every such type; for example, in Folly, you'd say

```
struct Widget {
    std::string s;
    std::vector<int> v;
};
FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE(Widget);
```

And this is a problem, because the average industry programmer shouldn't be bothered with trying to figure out if `std::string` is trivially relocatable on their library of choice. (The annotation above [is wrong](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/02/20/p1144-what-types-are-relocatable/) on 1.5 of the big 3 vendors!) Even [Folly's own maintainers](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/889) can't get these manual annotations right 100% of the time.

So the idea of P1144 is that the compiler can just take care of it for you. Your job changes from dangerously *warranting* things-you-don't-necessarily-know, to merely (and optionally) *verifying* things-you-want-to-be-true via `static_assert` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8Mce6abYc)):

```
struct Widget {
    std::string s;
    std::vector<int> v;
};
static_assert(std::is_trivially_relocatable_v<Widget>);

struct Gadget {
    std::string s;
    std::list<int> v;
};
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_relocatable_v<Gadget>);
```

In your (OP's) specific use-case, it sounds like you need to find out whether a given lambda type is trivially relocatable ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qoa7c648G)):

```
void f(std::list<int> v) {
    auto widget = [&]() { return v; };
    auto gadget = [=]() { return v; };
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_relocatable_v<decltype(widget)>);
    static_assert(!std::is_trivially_relocatable_v<decltype(gadget)>);
}
```

This is something you can't really do *at all* with Folly/BSL/EASTL, because their warranting mechanisms work only on named types at the global scope. You can't exactly `FOLLY_ASSUME_FBVECTOR_COMPATIBLE(decltype(widget))`.

Inside a `std::function`-like type, you're correct that it *would be* useful to know whether the captured type is trivially relocatable or not. But since you can't know that, the next best thing (and what you should do in practice) is to check `std::is_trivially_copyable`. That's the currently blessed type trait that literally means "This type is safe to `memcpy`, safe to skip the destructor of" — basically all the things you're going to be doing with it. Even if you knew that the type was exactly `std::unique_ptr<int>`, or whatever, **it would still be undefined behavior to memcpy it** in present-day C++, because the current standard *says* that you're not allowed to memcpy types that aren't trivially copyable.

(Btw, technically, P1144 doesn't change that fact. P1144 merely says that the *implementation* is allowed to elide the effects of relocation, which is a huge wink-and-nod to implementors that they should just use memcpy. But even P1144R6 doesn't make it legal for *ordinary non-implementor programmers* to memcpy non-trivially-copyable types: it leaves the door open for some compiler to implement, and some library implementation to use, a `__builtin_trivial_relocate` function that is in some magical sense distinguishable from a plain old memcpy.)

Finally, your last paragraph refers to `memcpy + memset(src,0,...)`. That's wrong. Trivial relocation is tantamount to *just* `memcpy`. If you care about the state of the source object afterward — if you care that it's all-zero-bytes, for example — then that must mean you're going to look at it again, which means you aren't actually treating it as destroyed, which means you aren't actually doing the semantics of a *relocate* here. "Copy and null out the source" is more often the semantics of a *move*. The point of relocation is to avoid that extra work.

Comment: Been wanting builtin `std` type trait support for 20+ years. Looking at https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1144r2.html#polls, there was certainly support for "is_trivially_relocatable<T> should be added to the <type_traits>. So I wonder why you fear it's addition is "quite possibly not ever"? Thank you for your efforts Arthur.

Comment: I feel like trivial relocatability *must* include the memset? Like just imagine unique_ptr, it's trivially relocatable only if you include the memset, and that's a type you definitely want to be able to use relocation on. Without it trivial relocatability becomes far less useful.

Comment: @user541686: No, there is no memset. If you care about the state of the source object afterward — if you care that it's all-zero-bytes, for example — then that must mean you're going to look at it again, which means you aren't actually treating it as destroyed. Vice versa, if you are indeed treating the source object as *destroyed*, then the state of its bits-and-bytes simply doesn't matter, so there's no sense in memsetting them to anything. Also, you can just try it out for yourself, if you read assembly: https://p1144.godbolt.org/z/7G3sY4qcb (GCC's codegen is better than Clang's here.)

Comment: It seems you're asking for destructive relocatability, whereas I (and others asking this) want non-destructive relocatability. Just like with moves, both are valid and useful; it depends on the situation. Neither one is better or worse. Given the analogy with moves, I would probably call your version `is_destructively_relocatable`, and leave `is_relocatable` for the non-destructive version.

Comment: @user541686 C++ already has a term for non-destructive relocation: “move”.

Comment: @user3840170 s/relocatable/trivially_relocatable/g in my comment if that helps you get it better. The point is to migrate `Widget` with memmove + memset while still keeping the original object destructible...

Comment: @user541686: After relocating-from the source, you can certainly default-construct an object at that address again (and in the cases you're thinking of, like `unique_ptr`, which [`is_trivially_value_initializable`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2782r0.html), that default constructor will be tantamount to memset). But more to the point, I think @user3840170 is right that your "memmove + memset" is what C++ calls "move-construction." The benefit of relocation over move-construction is that it lets us omit the memset.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: There might not be any guarantee whatsoever that default-construction is cheap, successful, or is even possible. If that's your argument then you might as well argue we don't need move semantics either, because you can just copy and then default-construct in the original location. And no, I disagree about the benefit. The real benefit of relocatability comes from it being *trivial*: it gives the callee the ability to just memcpy + memset, and know a priori (as with strings) that there's no further need for custom construction/destruction.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: As a concrete example, imagine having `array<string, N>` on the stack. It should be possible to move it into the heap with a pure vectorized memcpy + memset, versus a bunch of slower moves + destructions. (And before you argue my compiler sucks if it can't figure this out, remember this is exactly analogous to how `std::copy` implementations explicitly fall back to `memcpy` for trivial types.)

Comment: @user541686: That's fair. [The codegen for `array<string>`](https://godbolt.org/z/baY1snchj) is "basically" a memcpy+memset, but the compiler isn't smart enough to split the loops and turn them into actual memcpy/memset calls in the same way that it does with [`array<int>`](https://godbolt.org/z/EeeTesrMs) (where it sees "basically" a memcpy without memset, and goes ahead and does it). [The codegen for "relocate + default-construct"](https://godbolt.org/z/o4EaP3G5Y) helps the compiler just enough: individually, the compiler _can_ see that the relocate is a memcpy and the construct is a memset.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: I'm not sure I get what you're arguing for at this point, but to be *explicitly clear*: "just relocate and default construct on top" is an *crazy* answer to "I need non-destructive relocatability". Not every relocatable type is string. A default ctor might not (& *need not*) be present, let alone accessible, let alone cheap, for you to call. It's a desperate workaround. Your insistence on this is like insisting that people don't need move semantics because they can simulate it via copy + default-init. You're basically conceding that it's necessary but refusing to accommodate it.

Comment: @user541686: I'm saying, you're still 100% describing "move-construct." But you have a point that mainstream compilers aren't sufficiently smart to [fission the loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fission_and_fusion) for `array<string>`'s move-constructor into memcpy+memset. In this case, if that optimization matters to you, you can help the compiler find it by using "relocate + default-construct" instead of "move". I turned this into [a blog post](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2023/12/06/relocate-and-construct/) yesterday.

Comment: How do you even make sense of this operation yourself? If you std::relocate something from the stack, wouldn't it still get destructed when it goes out of scope? Meaning now you're destroying the original (which you *did not memset*)? Are you expecting the compiler to carry an extra boolean flag to suppress its destruction, and do you not think that would be a performance hit? Or do you really think memcpy on a std::string is safe with the old object still being destroyed?

Comment: @user541686: If you open a question here, I'll do my best to answer it. Alternatively, send me an email!

Comment: @Quuxplusone: I don't really have a question, I'm just explaining to you why your proposal makes no sense. Destructively relocating from the stack would leave the original vulnerable to double-destruction when it goes out of scope, is what I'm trying to tell you. Preventing that would incur a performance penalty in the general case.